# how to force Entity Manager to contain(attach) entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, ejb-3.0

I have a huge object(entity) that stores some vertexes and edges on it.I want to store this entity in server to access every time I want.  I will make some algorithms on it, So I do not want to load it from database every time. So I want it to be attached to Entity Manager until I detach. Of course I can  open another entity  , then old entity will be datached from entity manager, newly persisted entity will be detached.

I am using container managed bean. As you know, I  could not control transactions over container managed beans.

I have defined a Singeton bean and define this entity as an attribute inside it. As I understand, when I lookup bean every time, a new transaction is started, So entity manager does not contain my entity in persistence context. So entity manager tries to do so many select statements to attach object to persistence context. If I use Hibernate Session, entity is attached to session until I call session.close(). How can I do this using entity manager?

```
@Singleton
public class BEan implements BEanRemote {
   @PersistenceContext(unitName = "DBService")
   private EntityManager em;
  // ** newly opened entity.*/
   private Entity entity;

}
```

Comment: Hibernate has 2 levels of cache : session cache and session factory cache. Once you've loaded this entity once, those others calls should get the entity either from 1st level cache, or from 2nd level cache if the session has been closed. Thus, your entity would not be  loaded from database.

Comment: Daniel, em.contains return false.when I do em.merge after some changes, entity manager loads it  from database, does not from cache. this is behaviour in my program.Do I need to change/adapt something to obtain the behaviour you told.

Comment: In case you are changing the entity, and then you call `em.merge(entity)`, the entity should be updated in database, right? I don't think you want discrepancies between the data your program uses and the data from database. So you can't avoid that. But after that merge call ( or after you query again that entity), the cache will be updated so further calls will get the data from cache again.

Comment: The problem, when I select query again that entity, it results in one select. But when I make merge, it results in many selects with inner joins

Comment: When you call merge, your entity must be synched with the database. Since your entity is composed from multiple references to other entities, those entities too must be synched with the database. But before they are synched with the database(insert/update) their presence in the database must be check, hence the multiple select  calls.

Comment: Daniel, in this select statements, entity manager does not apply FetchType rules. It fetches all relations without considering if it is Eager or Lazy. If I select referenced entity with em.find, it considers fetch type rules.